# How to convince a research supervisor to proofread the paper?

Tags: publications, phd, advisor

I have written a paper, conceptualized, executed and written by me. I have sent it to my supervisor for proof reading and it has been more than a month, he has been sitting on it, without any comments or any progress. It is the first paper I have written and do not have much experience of sending it. I have been calling my supervisor but he ignores the call. He even sees the messages and does not reply.

He is very polite in nature, though it is very hard to get things done from him.

What are the methods you have been using to get things done, by your supervisor.

Comment: By "proof reading" do you mean looking for typos, checking for grammar and spelling mistakes, and the like? If so, I recommend that you not ask your supervisor to do this. Better to ask questions on the content or on the overall presentation.

Comment: By proof read, is to have one last final look at the manuscript, for any suggestions, after all his name will also be on the paper. The content, I have already explained to him in a presentation, and if he has doubts I can still clear it, before getting tangled up in publication.

Comment: I think you will need to manage your supervisor. Try to get hold of him in person (if necessary, call him) and ask him for a timeframe where you an expect a response. If he cannot be managed despite your attempts, you'd better run.

Comment: @ChetanWaghela Also, is it the final exam period at your university? If so, you'll probably have good luck a week or so after that's concluded.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can send him a ***small piece of work at a time***, such as the introduction.

Try to ***utilise his/her time for the most important part of the work***. For the introduction, you can ask him/her to proofread your contributions paragraph.